Failed to send request: [AxiosError: Network Error] on expo android only. Working on web
const sendRequest = async () => {
    try {
      setIsLoading(true);

      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("description", description);
      formData.append("quantity", quantity);
      formData.append("pickup_date", date.toISOString());
      formData.append("pickup_time", time.toISOString());
      formData.append("address", location);
      formData.append("phone", phoneNumber);

      for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        const image = images[i];
        if (image) {
          const response = await fetch(image.uri);
          const blob = await response.blob();
          formData.append(`image_${i + 1}`, blob, `image_${i + 1}.jpg`);
        }
      }

      const response = await axios.post(API.postOrder, formData, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_API_TOKEN}`,
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      });

      if (response?.data?.status === "success") {
        toggleModal();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Failed to send request:", error);
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

Here is my code. It is working on Expo Web but not working on Expo Android.
If I comment on the for loop part where I am appending the image blob. It works on Android too.
